# Derivative of the Fundamental Solution to the Laplace Equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The fundamental solution of Laplace equation is given as $\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)}\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}$ for $n \geq 3$. and $\alpha(n)$ is a constant

We want to check $$u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y)f(y)dy$$ solves the poisson’s equation.

A naive attempt will be to move the Laplacian to inside the Integral:  $$\Delta u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Delta \Phi(x-y)f(y)dy$$

But one cannot do it because $\Phi(x-y)$ is not summable near the singularity at $y=x$. My task is to show why.

A hint from my tutor is to show that $|D^2\Phi| \leq \frac{C}{|x|^n} \notin L^1(B_{\epsilon}(0))$

I don’t understand the $\notin$ part which means given an n-dimensional ball with radius $\epsilon$ centered at $0$ we should show:

$$\int_{B_{\epsilon}(0)}\frac{1}{|x|^n} = \infty$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto 1/|x|^n$ is the prime (the only) example of an $n$-th order pole: integrating it over any domain "containing" the origin will lead to an explosion. This is because that function is not locally integrable (and thus it does not define a distribution). Indeed, if we specialize to (punctured) balls centered at the origin,
$$\int_{B_\varepsilon(0)} \frac{dx}{|x|^n} = \int_0^\varepsilon \frac{1}{r^n} r^{n-1} dr \int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} d\Omega_{n-1} = \operatorname{vol}(\mathbb S^{n-1}) \cdot \ln r\Bigg|_{0}^\varepsilon = \infty,$$
where $\mathbb S^k$ is the unit $k$-sphere, $d\Omega_k$ is the $k$-dimensional solid angle element, and $r^{n-1}$ is the radial part of the hyperspherical jacobian in $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Just to clarify, does the vol(Surface) mean the area of this surface?

Comment: @PeterLai $\operatorname{vol}(M)$ for a $k$-dimensional compact manifold is its $k$-dimensional volume. For $n=2$ you get $2\pi$ (length of unit circumference), for $n=3$ you get $4\pi$ (total solid angle), etc.